# convert nested conditions string to flat string

Tags: python, pandas

I have string which contains conditions like this:

```
"((A < 5 & B < -500) & C < 0.05)"
```

i want to convert this to `"(A < 5) & (B < -500) & (C < 0.05)"`. i need it in this format becasue i want to apply the condition on a dataframe.

If i use this  `"((A < 5 & B < -500) & C < 0.05)"` im getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

Comment: Are *all* of the conditions `&`-ed together?

Comment: Perhaps something like `'(' + ') & ('.join(cond.replace('(', '').replace(')','').split(' & ')) + ')'`

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Your expression is wrong because 5 & B is evaluated before A < 5 then B < -500

```
"((A < 5 & B < -500) & C < 0.05)"
```

You expression should be:

```
"((A < 5) & (B < -500)) & (C < 0.05)"
```

The expression above **is** equivalent to:

```
"(A < 5) & (B < -500) & (C < 0.05)"
```

But `((A < 5 & B < -500) & C < 0.05)` **is different than** `(A < 5) & (B < -500) & (C < 0.05)`